# Jquery: Cloning a select list and selecting an option by its value

Tags: jquery, attributes, jquery-selectors, html-manipulation

I'm trying to append a select option list to a div table with jQuery, after done this, I'd like to select a specific option of the list, I'm trying something like this:

```
// my hidden option list
<div style="display:none;">
<select class="option_list">
    <option value="male">Male</option>
    <option value="female">Female</option>
    <option value="none">Unknown</option>
</select>
</div>

<div id="my_table">
    <div>
        <div>John</div>
        <div>25</div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>Emy</div>
        <div>22</div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>Sarah</div>
        <div>28</div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
</div>

// $(".option_list") is hidden in HTML page, I clone and append it to my div table row
$(".option_list")
      .clone ()
      .appendTo ("#my_table > div > div:last-child")
      .attr ("name", "a_dynamic_name_for_php_form")
      .find ("option[value=none]").selected = true;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(".option_list")
  .clone ()
  .appendTo ("#my_table > div > div:last-child")
  .attr ("name", "a_dynamic_name_for_php_form")
  .find ("option[value=none]").attr("selected", "true");
```

Notice the change in the last line.

Answer (score 0):

You should write `.val('none')`.  The `val` method will find the `<option>` with that `value`.  (Or, failing that, that text)

Comment: I've tried this but seem to set all the options to value 'none'

Comment: You of course need to do that on the `select` element, not on all `option` elements.

Answer (score -1):

Why clone it? As simple as it may be, I would define hidden html parts as string and simply append them:

```
var add = '<select>' +
          '  <option value="one">one</option>' +
          '  <option two ... '+
          '</select>';
$(something).appendTo(add);
```

Bit dirty, but... :) - (you could even define those hidden parts with asp/php, so you don't have to write each line)

**Edit**: already answered...